# Uploading files to S3 using AmazonS3Client.java api

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3

I am using AmazonS3Client.java to upload files to S3 from my application. I am using the putObject method to upload the file

```
val putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, inputStream, metadata)
val acl = CannedAccessControlList.Private
putObjectRequest.setCannedAcl(acl)
s3.putObject(putObjectRequest)
```

This works for buckets at the topmost level in my S3 account. Now, suppose i want to upload the file to a sub-bucket for example bucketB which is inside bucketA . How should i specify the bucket name for bucketB ?

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

It is admittedly somewhat surprising, but there is no such thing as a "sub-bucket" in S3.  All buckets are top-level.  The structures inside buckets that you see in the S3 admin console or other UIs are called "folders", but even they don't really exist!  You can't directly create or destroy folders, for instance, or set any attributes on them.  Folders are purely a presentation-level convention for viewing the underlying flat set of objects in your bucket. That said, it's pretty easy to split your objects into (purely non-existent) folders.  Just give them heirarchical names, with each level separated by a "/".

```
val putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, topFolderName +"/" + subFolderName+ "/" +key, inputStream, metadata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying using `putObjectRequest.setKey("folder")`